# Spring Batch - JdbcCursorItemReader throwing OutOfMemoryError with large MySQL table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, spring-batch

I am writing a program using Spring Batch to process 7,637,064 rows from a MySQL database table. I've had success with smaller tables, but the large number of rows in this table is causing OutOfMemoryError exceptions when the JdbcCursorItemReader attempts to open the cursor.

I could probably resolve this by throwing a larger Xmx at it, but it seems to me that Spring Batch should have a way to handle this and that I may simply be missing a key piece of configuration.

Spring Batch configuration:

```
  <job id="reportJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="largeTableTransfer">
      <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="largeTableReader" processor="largeTableTransformer" writer="largeTableWriter"
          commit-interval="10" />
      </tasklet>
    </step>
  </job>

  <bean id="largeTableReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="inputDataSource" />
    <property name="sql" value="select * from largeTable" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
      <bean class="myproject.reader.largeTableRowMapper" />
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="largeTableTransformer" class="myproject.transformer.LargeTableTransformer" />
  <bean id="largeTableWriter" class="myproject.writer.JdbcLargeTableWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="outputDataSource" />
  </bean>
```

Setting *fetchSize* on the JdbcCursorItemReader appears to have no effect. The only thing that allows it to run to completion is to set the *maxRows* to a small number, but then only that number of rows get processed.

The relevant stack trace:

```
2012-11-21 11:25:29,931 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcStepExecutionDao] - <Truncating long message before update of StepExecution, original message is: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2734)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(ArrayList.java:167)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:351)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:2821)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:467)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:2510)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:1746)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2135)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader.openCursor(JdbcCursorItemReader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:93)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:301)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:192)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:293)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
    at ifpress.ams2amx.ExampleJobConfigurationTests.testLaunchJob(ExampleJobConfigurationTests.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue in MySql JDBC driver which causes loading of the whole dataset into memory regardless of the parameters you have passed to the statement creation method. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html for how properly open a cursor.

Here is how I do it:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
  <property name="verifyCursorPosition" value="false" />
   <property name="dataSource" ref="remoteDataSource" />
   <property name="rowMapper">
     <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SingleColumnRowMapper" />
   </property>
   <property name="fetchSize">
     <util:constant static-field="java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE" />
   </property>
   <property name="sql">
     <value>SELECT foo, bar FROM baz</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me understand the issue, however by using these settings I now get the following error: "Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@451710be is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries." have you ever seen this?

Comment: I have definitely seen this a couple of times, but I don't remember why this happened. If you could provide a little bit more information,  e.g. the context sources or a full log output, I might recall the problem origin.

Comment: I had to move past this and I solved my particular situation by breaking it into multiple jobs processing a certain number of rows each. More cumbersome from a configuration perspective, but has the extra benefit of allowing multiple jobs to run in parallel if available memory allows it. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: thanks for the verifyCursorPosition=false, it seems required for MySQL ResultSet streaming processing. Check https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-1252