# Spring batch JdbcCursorItemReader cause a memory not enough issue

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am using the spring batch framework to do a data migration. The reader I use is JdbcCursorItemReader. I set chunk size as 500 and set the reader fetch size as 1000. But when run the service with spring batch it just seems to read all the data once in the memory and run out of the memory . then throw a memory not enough issue. Below is how I define the reader:

```
   private JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>> buildItemReader(final DataSource dataSource, String tableName,String tenant) {
        String tenantName = tenantHelper.determineTenant(tableName);
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>> itemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        itemReader.setSql("select * from " + tableName + " where " + tenantName + " ='" + tenant + "'");
        itemReader.setRowMapper(new ColumnMapRowMapper());
        itemReader.setFetchSize(100);
        return itemReader;
    }
```

Whats more, from the spring batch document [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#cursorBasedItemReaders), we should be able to avoid the memory issue by using the jdbcCursorItemReader

Comment: Obviously the query will fetch full result only because you don't have a limit in size. I think you need `Partitioner`

Comment: Hi @soorapadman ,Does the Partitioner mean to split the process to more steps? For certain reasons I could not use that function because I have to create step dynamicly. I am also thinking about to use the jdbcPagingItemReader. But the paging also do not work for me , I also tried as described in this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369572/spring-batch-jdbcpagingitemreader-paging-not-work

Comment: The fetch size is just a hint to the database driver and its implementation depends on the database product. Which database do you use?

Comment: I am using the postgresql. And I debuged the jdbcCursorItemReader, it did read/write by the fetch size and chunk size. But i am just confused why it use all the memory and load all the data to the memory

Comment: ok thanks for the update. I added an answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out by using the jdbcPagingItemReader. The root cause that the the cursor reader consume massive memory is because it just read all the data into the memory and  then process it, which will be considered as a big object by the JVM and it will be allocated into the old generation directlly, Until the whole process finished, it could not be collected.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using a [JdbcPagingItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/old/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html) instead of JdbcCursorItemReader where the page size can be set while configuring it

Comment: Thanks I have figured this out by using the JdbcPagingItemReader

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most

Answer (score 2):

> i am just confused why it use all the memory and load all the data to the memory

According to [Postgresql's documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/83/query.html#query-with-cursor), the driver collects all the results for a query at once.

You can probably try to turn the cursor off by setting the fetch size to 0. There are other constraints as explained in the aforementioned doc, please make sure your code meets all of them. Just for reference, this is similar to what might happen with MySQL where the fetch size should be set to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to stream results (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497822) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588433)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for your reply, you are right that the cursor reader i used will just fetch all the results at once which will make up a big object and goes into the old generation directlly. That's the root cause of my problem. I have tried to configure the fetch size but it turns out that did not work for me. I finally solve this by using the paging reader